# Execute a PHP file built on the fly?

Tags: php

I have a web page that has input parameters for a php file that I want to execute on the server.

For example:
THe web asks for 2 variables (X & Y)

I then need to call a php file with X & Y
`Php test.php -x "X" -y "Y"`

But I'm stumped!

Comment: You can use `shell_exec` to pass the arguments to another PHP instance. Or depending on how the `test.php` script is written, you could `include` it in your main php file and call it from there

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? It would be better if the PHP file defined a function, you `require` the file, then use `function_name($X, $Y);`

Comment: Can't you just submit X and Y in a form and get your webserver to run the php script?

Comment: "But I'm stumped!" - why? What does that mean? Anything not working as expected?